# Update table header view frame with layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the frame of a table header view in a `UITableViewController`.  The only way to do that seems to be setting it again like this.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = someView;
```

I want to do this in `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` but when you do that there it causes an infinite loop.  So how do you adjust the table view header frame when the view size changes?

Comment: You could try adding a check `if (self.tableView.tableHeaderView != someView) self.tableView.tableHeaderView = someView;` to guard against unwanted repetitions.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked to check the frame of the `tableHeaderView` to see if it needs to be adjusted so it doesn't keep repeating.